# How to override the [] operator in Python?

Tags: python, operator-overloading

What is the name of the method to override the `[]` operator (subscript notation) for a class in Python?

Answer (score 449, accepted):

You need to use the [`__getitem__` method](https://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getitem__).

```
class MyClass:
    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return key * 2

myobj = MyClass()
myobj[3] #Output: 6
```

And if you're going to be setting values you'll need to implement the [`__setitem__` method](https://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__setitem__) too, otherwise this will happen:

```
>>> myobj[5] = 1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: MyClass instance has no attribute '__setitem__'
```

Answer (score 90):

To fully overload it you also need to implement the `__setitem__`and `__delitem__` methods.

**edit**

I almost forgot... if you want to completely emulate a list, you also need `__getslice__, __setslice__ and __delslice__`.

There are all documented in http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html

Comment: `__getslice__, `__setslice__` and `__delslice__' have been deprecated for the last few releases of ver 2.x (not sure exactly when), and are no longer supported in ver 3.x.  Instead, use `__getitem__`. `__setitem__` and `__delitem__' and test if the argument is of type `slice`, i.e.: `if isinstance(arg, slice): ...

Answer (score 24):

You are looking for the `__getitem__` method. See http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html, section 3.4.6