# Python array slicing -- How can 2D array slicing be implemented?

Tags: python, arrays, slice

I am wondering how 2D array slicing can be implemented in Python?

For example,

`arr` is an instance of a self-defined class 2D array.

if I want to enable 2D slicing syntax on this object like this:

```
arr[:,1:3] #retrieve the 1 and 2 column values of every row
```

or

```
arr[,:3] #retrieve the 1 and 2 column values of every row
```

The usage and syntax is just like numpy.array. But how can this kind of functionality be realized on our own?

**PS:**

What I have in mind:

for the first case, the `[:,1:3]` part is like a tuple of two slices

However, for the second case `[,1:3]` appears to be quite mysterious.

Comment: If you are implementing a class similar to a numpy class and want similar behavior, why not just check their code?

Comment: you want to make your own implementation, or do you want to know how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`obj[,:3]` is not valid python so it will raise a `SyntaxError` -- Therefore, you *can't* have that syntax in your source file.  (It fails when you try to use it on a `numpy` array as well)

Comment: *jokes* I suppose we could always hope they add that syntax in the python4.0 series ...

Comment: Ah, Thanks for reminding the mistakes! I think I have the clue now!

Comment: True, `obj[,:3]` is not valid syntax, but you could implement both `obj[:,:3]` or `obj[None,:3]` as these are valid syntax....

Answer (score 12):

If you want to know the rules of array slicing, the picture below might help:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

For read access you need to override the `__getitem__` method:

```
class ArrayLike(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def __getitem__(self, arg):
        (rows,cols) = arg # unpack, assumes that we always pass in 2-arguments
        # TODO: parse/interpret the rows/cols parameters,
        # for single indices, they will be integers, for slices, they'll be slice objects
        # here's a dummy implementation as a placeholder 
        return numpy.eye(10)[rows, cols]
```

One of the tricky bits is that `__getitem__` always only uses one argument (aside from self),
when you put multiple-comma-separated items inside the square brackets, you're actually providing a single tuple as the argument to the `__getitem__` call; thus the need to
unpack this tuple (and optionally verify that the length of the tuple is suitable) inside
the function.

Now given `a = ArrayLike()`, you end up with

- `a[2,3]` means `rows=2`, `cols=3`
- `a[:3,2]` means `rows=slice(None, 3, None)`, `cols=3`

and so on; you'll have to look at the [documentation on slice objects](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#slice) to decide
how you want to use the slice information to pull out the data that you need from your class.

To make it more like a numpy array, you'd also want to override `__setitem__` as well, to 
allow for assigning to elements/slices.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a hack if it's your own class and you are willing to pass in a string.

[How to override the [] operator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1957780/python-overloading-the-operator-getitem-method)

```
class Array(object):

    def __init__(self, m, n):
        """Create junk demo array."""
        self.m = m
        self.n = n
        row = list(range(self.n))
        self.array = map(lambda x:row, range(self.m))

    def __getitem__(self, index_string):
        """Implement slicing/indexing."""

        row_index, _, col_index = index_string.partition(",")

        if row_index == '' or row_index==":":
            row_start = 0
            row_stop = self.m
        elif ':' in row_index:
            row_start, _, row_stop = row_index.partition(":")
            try:
                row_start = int(row_start)
                row_stop = int(row_stop)
            except ValueError:
                print "Bad Data"
        else:
            try:
                row_start = int(row_index)
                row_stop = int(row_index) + 1
            except ValueError:
                print "Bad Data"

        if col_index == '' or col_index == ":":
            col_start = 0
            col_stop = self.n
        elif ':' in col_index:
            col_start, _, col_stop = col_index.partition(":")
            try:
                col_start = int(col_start)
                col_stop = int(col_stop)
            except ValueError:
                print "Bad Data"
        else:
            try:
                col_start = int(col_index)
                col_stop = int(col_index) + 1
            except ValueError:
                print "Bad Data"

        return map(lambda x: self.array[x][col_start:col_stop],
                       range(row_start, row_stop))

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.array)

    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self.array)


array = Array(4, 5)
print array
out: [[0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]]

array[",1:3"]
out: [[1, 2], [1, 2], [1, 2], [1, 2]]

array[":,1:3"]
out: [[1, 2], [1, 2], [1, 2], [1, 2]]
```