# Can you change the indexing in python?

Tags: python, arrays, indexing

What I mean by this is may I change the calling index of an array. For example, if I have array a = [1,2,3] can I make it so a[1] = 1? I know this is an option in FORTRAN which certainly keeps things organized and legible. Thanks

Comment: do you mean your array index starts at 1, instead of 0?

Comment: dictionaries are good for this, perhaps.

Comment: If you explain your circumstance and *why* you want to do this then I am sure there is a solution. In general the solution would be to subclass the `list` type, but I doubt if that is necessary

Comment: Haha, "which certainly keeps things organized and legible".

Comment: I just wanted to know if there was a simple solution. other than adding a dummy element

Comment: @user2 864740: My thoughts exactly! This is *possible* in Perl, but it is documented with severe admonishments *not* to *ever* do it.

Comment: @handroski: As I said, there probably is a simple solution, but you haven't told us the *problem* you're trying to solve by doing this.

Comment: You can probably redefine `__getitem__` and its friends (I'm not sure if you'd really want to do that). See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1957780/python-overloading-the-operator-getitem-method

Comment: You can easily make it so that a[1-1] = 1.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Changing the indexing of a list in Python is almost definitely not what you want to do as it will break `len(some_list)`, lead to off-by-one errors of valid input, and iteration.  Starting at index[1] runs counter to most of the language's design.

Python's lists are implemented on top of C arrays (see [listobject.c in the Python source](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/5f001ad90373/Objects/listobject.c)), which are indexed starting at 0.

If you're positive that you need to start counting at one, consider initializing your lists by setting `a[0]` to `None` so that you're it's clear that you're inserting a dummy value.

Comment: Wonderful solution. Thank you

Comment: No problem.  You could also create a function that returns a list with `None` prepended, but please note that `None` is falsey.

Comment: Note that adding a dummy value will essentially break `len(a)` as well as iteration

Comment: Oh yeah, @PeterGibson, definitely not advisable because it means reinventing a lot of functions to handle the off-by-one error that accompanying changing the C underpinnings.

Comment: seems to register fine using len(a). Returns empty space when called. Im wondering what will happen if I attempt to plot.

Comment: Adding your comment to my answer @PeterGibson, I should have included the warning alongside my disclaimer of "this is not what you want, but..."

Comment: operations on that element are a big no. This is fine for me because itll be a warning that I am off by one is my array operations. Thanks again @tristan,@Peter Gibson

Comment: @tristan: I assume the OP doesn't mean to use `mylist[1]` to access `mylist[0]`, but rather that, say, `mylist[1900]` doesn't require 1,900 wasted elements to be declared, and that `mylist.append('x')` on an ampty list assigns the value to `mylist[1900]`. I think it just needs a class.

Comment: @Borodin I'm not going to assume what OP means --  if he decides that he actually wants a reserved-but-not-initialized list, I'll let him ask for it.

Answer (score 4):

Although in general it is inadvisable, you are free to extend built-in types, for example:

```
# Python 3 syntax
class FiveList(list):
    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        return super().__getitem__(idx - 5)

>>> FiveList(range(100))[10]
5
```

You'd have to implement a whole lot of magic methods (below), and also check if argument is int-like (index) or a slice.

```
__getitem__
__setitem__
__delitem__
```

Also, watch out for negative indices, as those are special in Python.

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing more about your application is is difficult to help, but it may be useful for you to read [Emulating Container Types](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#emulating-container-types).

I suggest that if you were to write a class, say `BasedArray`, that had an integer `base` attribute that specified the index of the first element, and a normal zero-based `list` that held the data. Then you could get away with writing just the `__len__`, `__get item__` and `__setitem__` methods, which would be trivial, and probably `__iter__` which is less so. The exact set of methods you need depends on what you want to *do* with these based arrays once you have them.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you mean start index at 1, instead of 0?

Why not just put 0 at the start? E.g.

```
 [0,1,2,3]
```

Comment: Thats what I do now but, I need to do operations involving many arrays. So this will eventually give me trouble

Comment: there is no way to actually skip 0 index in python.