# python: replace elements in list with conditional

Tags: python, list

I am trying to do the following with python and am having a strange behavior. Say I have the following list:

```
x = [5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
```

Now, I am doing something like:

```
x[x >= 3] = 3
```

This gives:

```
x = [5, 3, 3, 2, 1]
```

Why does only the second element get changed? I was expecting:

```
[3, 3, 3, 2, 1]
```

Comment: Why I got an error `TypeError: unorderable types: list() >= int()`?

Comment: @KevinGuan You're using python3, Luca's using python2

Comment: @NightShadeQueen Well, why doesn't Python 3 support this?

Comment: @KevinGuan: because Python 3 prevents you from making the mistake Luca made, which is to compare a list object with an integer.

Comment: These questions get asked every day. And the answer is always a list comprehension/filter, perhaps people should search better, or there needs to be a sticky. I'm amazed answers get upvoted so much for the same thing twice every day.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Because Python will evaluated the `x>=3` as `True` and since `True` is equal to 1 so the second element of `x` will be converted to 3.

For such purpose you need to use a list comprehension :

```
>>> [3 if i >=3 else i for i in x]
[3, 3, 3, 2, 1]
```

And if you want to know that why `x >= 3` evaluates as True, see the following [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#comparisons) :

> CPython implementation detail: Objects of different types except numbers are ordered by their type names; objects of the same types that don’t support proper comparison are ordered by their address.

In python-2.x and CPython implementation of course, a list is always greater than an integer type.As a string is greater than a list :

```
>>> ''>[]
True
```

In Python-3.X, however, you can't compare unorderable types together and you'll get a `TypeError` in result.

```
In [17]: '' > []
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-17-052e7eb2f6e9> in <module>()
----> 1 '' > []

TypeError: unorderable types: str() > list()
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use this syntax with [Numpy](http://www.numpy.org):

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> x = np.array([5, 4, 3, 2, 1])
>>> x[x>3]=3
>>> x
array([3, 3, 3, 2, 1])
```

You can also do this with [Pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org):

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> x = pd.Series([5, 4, 3, 2, 1])
>>> x
0    5
1    4
2    3
3    2
4    1
dtype: int64
>>> x[x>3]=3
>>> x
0    3
1    3
2    3
3    2
4    1
dtype: int64
```

Comment: This actually solved my doubt, because I saw this syntax in pandas code and wasn't sure if it was due to python, or pandas. Any tip on how I could have known by looking at pandas code and/or documentation without the help of stackoverflow?

Comment: My own answer, in case anyone else is interested: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html - Pandas and Numpy override the [] operator with __getitem__ as per https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1957780/how-to-override-the-operator-in-python

Answer (score 5):

You're using python lists.  In python(2.x), comparison of a `list` with an `int` will compare the *types*, not the values.  So, your comparison results in `True` which is equivalent to `1`.  In other words, your expression is equivalent to:

```
x[1] = 3  # x[1] == x[True] == x[x > 3]
```

Note, python3.x disallows this type of comparison (because it's almost certainly not what you meant) -- And if you want to be doing this sort of operation, you almost certainly thought of it by looking at `numpy` documentation as the numpy API has been designed specifically to support this sort of thing:

```
import numpy as np
array = np.arange(5)
array[array > 3] = 3
```

Comment: And note that numbers are special cased to always sort before other types.

Comment: @MartijnPieters -- Well... That's CPython.  IIRC, other implementations can define any sort order they want -- Just so long as it is consistent.

Comment: Honestly prefer list comprehension to this. One less library to import :)

Comment: @mgilson: sure, which could even mean they sort by `id(type(obj))`. But most implementations want to stay consistent with Python 2.x and do reimplement that behaviour.

Comment: @akalikin -- That's fair.  If this is the _only_ place in the code where you're going to do something like this, it's probably not worth the overhead of importing/learning numpy.  However, it seems to me that it would be rare to have this sort of operation in the code only one time -- At which point using `numpy` can be a huge advantage.

Comment: @akalikin: mgilson is explaining why the OP might have gotten confused and thought the standard Python list type might support the same kinds of operations.