# confused about Python list syntax

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, scikit-learn

Here is the code and related document (http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.datasets.load_iris.html#sklearn.datasets.load_iris), I am confused by this line, `data.target[[10, 25, 50]]`, confused why using double `[[]]`, if anyone could clarify, it will be great.

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
data = load_iris()
print data.target[[10, 25, 50]]
print list(data.target_names)
```

thanks in advance,
Lin

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 Looks like `[10, 25, 50]` are being indexed from the `data.target` array

Comment: @TigerhawkT3, thanks and vote up. I tried `print type(data.target)`, return is `<type 'numpy.ndarray'>`. Confused what do you mean list containing a single element, could you help to elaborate a bit more? Thanks.

Comment: @cricket_007, thanks and vote up, but why using double `[[]]`?

Comment: You are confused about NumPy arrays, then, not Python lists.

Comment: Thanks @cricket_007, vote up. Then what is the meaning here for double `[[]]` in `[[10, 25, 50]]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your confusion is understandable: this isn't "standard" Python by any means.

`data.target` in this case is an [`ndarray`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.html) from numpy:

```
In [1]: from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
   ...: data = load_iris()
   ...: print data.target[[10, 25, 50]]
   ...: print list(data.target_names)
[0 0 1]
['setosa', 'versicolor', 'virginica']

In [2]: print type(data.target)
<type 'numpy.ndarray'>
```

numpy's ndarray implementation allows you to create a new array by providing a list of indices of the items you want. For example:

```
In [13]: data.target
Out[13]:
array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
       1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
       1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2,
       2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2,
       2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2])

In [14]: data.target[1]
Out[14]: 0

In [15]: data.target[[1,2,3]]
Out[15]: array([0, 0, 0])

In [16]: print type(data.target[[1,2,3]])
<type 'numpy.ndarray'>
```

and it likely does this by [overriding `__getitem__`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1957780/how-to-override-operator).

For more information, see [Indexing](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html) in the NumPy array documentation:

Comment: Thanks Christian, vote up for the comprehensive reply, so it means retrieve `10, 25, 50`-th element from `numpy` array `data.target` and for a new list in Python? If so `type(data.target[[10, 25, 50]])` should be a formal Python list, correct?

Comment: @LinMa Look at the last line of code in the answer, it is still a `numpy.ndarray`

Comment: Thanks @cricket_007, vote up. It is all clear now. :)

Comment: You can, in many ways, treat a `numpy.ndarray` as a list (iterating over it, slicing into it, etc.) but if you're going to do so I highly recommend reading [the documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.html) first, as there are some nonstandard behaviors that may trip you up.

Comment: Thanks Christian, vote up and mark your reply as answer.

Answer (score 1):

This is retrieving elements from a numpy array `A` using "integer indexing" syntax (as opposed to the usual subscripts), i.e. a list of integers `B` will be used to find elements at those particular indices in `A`. Your output is a numpy array with the same shape as the list `B` that you use as "input", and the values of the output elements are obtained from the values of `A` at those integer indices e.g.:

```
>>> import numpy
>>> a = numpy.array([0,1,4,9,16,25,36,49,64,81])
>>> a[[1,4,4,1,5,6,6,5]]
  array([ 1, 16, 16,  1, 25, 36, 36, 25])
```

Integer indexing can be applied to more than one dimensions, e.g.:

```
>>> b = numpy.array([[0,1,4,9,16],[25,36,49,64,81]]) # 2D array
>>> b[[0,1,0,1,1,0],[0,1,4,3,2,3]]   # row and column integer indices
  array([ 0, 36, 16, 64, 49,  9])
```

or, the same example but with an input list of *2* dimensions, affecting the *output* shape:

```
>>> b[[[0,1,0],[1,1,0]],[[0,1,4],[3,2,3]]] # "row" and "column" 2D integer arrays
  array([[ 0, 36, 16],
         [64, 49,  9]])
```

Also note that you can perform "integer indexing" using a numpy array as well, rather than a list, e.g.

```
>>> a[numpy.array([0,3,2,4,1])]
  array([ 0,  9,  4, 16,  1])
```