# Python infinitely repeated element in list

Tags: python, list

I have a list `l = [1, 2, 3]` and I want `l[2->infinity] == 3`. It would essentially look like `[1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, ...]`. I tried:

```
[1, 2, *3]
```

or

```
[1, 2, 3, ...]
```

Is there anyway to add a "default element" for a range of indices?

**Clarification**

I don't want to repeat the element `n` times because I can't index outside the length of the list. I want to actually have a value for all indexes from `2->infinity`. Some sort of default value for that index range.

Comment: Python lists are finite. We're not Haskell here.

Comment: Nominating this question for reopening because of the clarification. I think the actual answer to Harry's question is to override `__getitem__` (I think the question's details make it unique enough, but if it's a duplicate, then it's a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1957780/how-to-override-the-operator-in-python)

Comment: Agreed. It wasn't obvious from the title of the question, but when the OP asked for "add[ing] a 'default element' for a range of indices" then yes it's clear that `__getitem__` is the way to go. That would be a better way to get `a[1000000]` efficiently for sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alternatively to Chris answer, you can create your own generator:

```
def inf3():
    yield 1
    yield 2
    while True:
        yield 3

>>> g = inf3()
>>> [next(g) for _ in range(100)]
[1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3]
```

Answer (score 8):

The best way I can think of is to chain two iterators together, like so:

```py
from itertools import *

chain([1, 2], repeat(3))
```

REPL example:

```py
>>> list(islice(chain([1, 2], repeat(3)), 10))
[1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3]
```