# Python set dictionary nested key with dot delineated string

Tags: python, dictionary

If I have a dictionary that is nested, and I pass in a string like `"key1.key2.key3"` which would translate to:

```
myDict["key1"]["key2"]["key3"]
```

What would be an elegant way to be able to have a method where I could pass on that string and it would translate to that key assignment? Something like 
`myDict.set_nested('key1.key2.key3', someValue)`

Comment: I believe the following question can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1957780/how-to-override-the-operator-in-python

Comment: I did this. https://github.com/AndroxxTraxxon/cfgutils

Comment: This seems like what you're trying to do: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14692690/access-nested-dictionary-items-via-a-list-of-keys

Answer (score 4):

Using only builtin stuff:

```
def set(my_dict, key_string, value):
    """Given `foo`, 'key1.key2.key3', 'something', set foo['key1']['key2']['key3'] = 'something'"""

    # Start off pointing at the original dictionary that was passed in.
    here = my_dict

    # Turn the string of key names into a list of strings.
    keys = key_string.split(".")

    # For every key *before* the last one, we concentrate on navigating through the dictionary.
    for key in keys[:-1]:
        # Try to find here[key]. If it doesn't exist, create it with an empty dictionary. Then,
        # update our `here` pointer to refer to the thing we just found (or created).
        here = here.setdefault(key, {})

    # Finally, set the final key to the given value
    here[keys[-1]] = value


myDict = {}
set(myDict, "key1.key2.key3", "some_value")
assert myDict == {"key1": {"key2": {"key3": "some_value"}}}
```

This traverses `myDict` one key at a time, ensuring that each sub-key refers to a nested dictionary.

You could also solve this recursively, but then you risk RecursionError exceptions without any real benefit.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of existing modules that will already do this, or something very much like it.  For example, the [jmespath module](https://pypi.org/project/jmespath/) will resolve [jmespath](http://jmespath.org/) expressions, so given:

```py
>>> mydict={'key1': {'key2': {'key3': 'value'}}}
```

You can run:

```py
>>> import jmespath
>>> jmespath.search('key1.key2.key3', mydict)
'value'
```

The [jsonpointer](https://pypi.org/project/jsonpointer/) module does something similar, although it likes `/` for a separator instead of `.`.

Given the number of pre-existing modules I would avoid trying to write your own code to do this.

Comment: How can I do the opposite of search, and set nested dictionary path to a value?

Comment: is there no way to do this with dot notation?

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT: OP's clarification makes it clear that this answer isn't what he's looking for. I'm leaving it up here for people who find it by title.**

---

I implemented a class that did this a while back... it should serve your purposes.
I achieved this by overriding the default getattr/setattr functions for an object.

Check it out! [AndroxxTraxxon/cfgutils](https://github.com/AndroxxTraxxon/cfgutils)

This lets you do some code like the following...

```py
from cfgutils import obj

a = obj({
    "b": 123,
    "c": "apple",
    "d": {
        "e": "nested dictionary value"
    }
})

print(a.d.e)
>>> nested dictionary value
```