# Overriding constructors for list in python

Tags: python, constructor

Let's say I want to implement some **list class** in python with extra structure, like a new constructor. I wrote:

```
import random

class Lis(list):
    def __init__(self, n):
        self = []
        for i in range(n):
            self.append(random.randint(0, 30))
```

Now doing `Lis(3)` gives me an empty list. I don't know where I did it wrong.

Answer (score 2):

You are overriding the object with `self = []`

try the following

```
import random

class Lis(list):
    def __init__(self, n):
        for i in range(n):
            self.append(random.randint(0, 30))
```

Comment: thanks for this quick answer, you were too fast i can(t accept tou answer for the moment :)

Comment: `super().__init__()`

Comment: Maybe you asnwer is the most generalizable. The answer of @James looks a bit tricky. Maybe I'm wrong.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to return a list from object call

```py
class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        print "never called in this case"
    def __new__(cls):
        return [1,2,3]

obj = MyClass()
print(obj)
```

[How to return a value from __init__ in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2491819/how-to-return-a-value-from-init-in-python)

or if you want an modified object try:

```py
class MyClass:
    def __getitem__(self, key):
        not_self = []
        for i in range(n):
            not_self.append(random.randint(0, 30))
        return not_self
myobj = MyClass()

myobj[3] #Output: 6
```

[How to override the [] operator in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1957780/how-to-override-the-operator-in-python)

I am not sure if using self like you did is healthy.