# Is there a way of parametrizing custom types in Python?

Tags: python, python-typing

Is there any way of parametrizing new types created with `NewType`, similar to how `typing.Sequence` and the like can be parametrized with subscripts? Or of achieving a similar result by different means?

The below example illustrates what I would *like* to do, but it fails with `TypeError: 'function' object is not subscriptable`, because [`NewType`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#newtype) returns a function.

```
from typing import NewType, Sequence, TypeVar

T = TypeVar("T")
Type1 = NewType("Type1", float)
Type2 = NewType("Type2", Sequence[T])

Works = Sequence[Type1]
Fails = Type2[Type1]
```

The reason that I hoped to do this is that I am creating a dataclass where, in `__post_init__`, I would like to run some specific logic depending on the type of the attribute.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to override the \[\] operator in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1957780/how-to-override-the-operator-in-python)

Comment: @mkrieger1 Thanks! But the core of my question isn't about how to implement subscripting, but about how to parametrize custom types. I have edited the question to try to make this clearer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution in the section on [generics](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/generics.html) in the Mypy docs: subclass the appropriate type from the `typing` module. (Rather than trying to use `NewType`.) For example,

```
from typing import NewType, Sequence

Type1 = NewType("Type1", float)

class Type2(Sequence):
    pass

Works = Type2[Type1]
```

Answer (score 0):

`Type1` and `Type2` are of type `function` which is not subscriptable.  Even if you manually implement `__getitem__` (the builtin function for the square bracket [] operator) on `Type2` python will raise a TypeError.

If you really want to use square brackets on your type I recommend creating a class and implement `__getitem__` and `__setitem__`.

Here is a simple example of what the class might look like:

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        self.__type_lookup = {}

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return self.__type_lookup[key]
    
    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        self.__type_lookup[key] = value
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! But I am hoping to stick with the objects provided by the standard library's `typing` module. I'd rather avoid creating a new class and having to reinvent the wheel vis-a-vis type checking etc.

Comment: I think the emphasis on subscripting in my question was perhaps a mistake; what I am really asking is how one can parametrize a type created with `NewType` that features `TypeVar`. I will edit the question to clarify.

Comment: If you're concerned about type checking then you can do that with the `isinstance` builtin.