# Is there a way to have a list of 4 billion numbers in Python?

Tags: python, list, binary-search

I made a binary search function and I'm curious what would happen if I used it on 4 billion numbers, but I get a `MemoryError` every time I use it. Is there a way to store the list without this issue?

Comment: store it on disk in some file, don't load it all at once in memory, or install more RAM

Comment: It seems like what would happen if you used 4 billion numbers on it is a `MemoryError`

Comment: How much RAM does your computer have? `MemoryError` simply means your computer ran out of RAM.

Comment: What is the range of these numbers?  If they're much smaller than the bit size of your computer would allow, you could save considerable space by storing them in something like an `array` (built-in module) or `numpy` (3rd-party module) array.

Comment: What do you mean by *array*?

Comment: Anyway, on a modern machine with something like 64 gigabytes of RAM, you could easily store an array of 64bit numbers, which would cost about 32 gigs.

Comment: Hmm, *"binary **sort** function"*? What is that?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but it's gonna be expensive.

Assuming the numbers are 1-4,000,000,000, each number would take up either 28 bytes or 32 bytes. Going with 32 bytes, storing 4,000,000,000 numbers would take ~128GB. The list itself also takes up memory, 8 bytes per object [(source)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/449560/how-do-i-determine-the-size-of-an-object-in-python), so it would require around 192GB of memory altogether.

If you're wanting to *emulate* a list, however, things become a lot more reasonable.

If your numbers follow some formula, you can make a class that "pretends" to be a list by following the answers [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1957780/how-to-override-the-operator-in-python) This will create a custom class that works like a list, (e.g. you can do `foo[3]` on it and it will return a number) but doesn't take up all that memory because it isn't actually storing 4,000,000,000 numbers. In fact, this is pretty similar to how `range()` works, and is the reason why doing `range(1,4_000_000_000)` doesn't take up 192GB of ram.

Comment: Or you could use an array instead of a list.