# How is the square bracket operator implemented for pandas GroupBy objects?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, indexing, group-by, operator-overloading

In Python 3.11: to apply the square brackets operator to an object, [the object's `__getitem__` method should be implemented](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1957793/1818935).

In Python's `pandas` module it is possible to apply square brackets to objects returned from a `DataFrame` by the `groupby()` method, e.g. `tips.groupby("sex")["total_bill"].count()`. (Example taken from [this tutorial](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/getting_started/comparison/comparison_with_sql.html#group-by).)

However, there's no `__getitem__` method listed in the [`pandas`' API reference for `GroupBy` objects](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/groupby.html). How come? How is the square bracket operator implemented for `pandas` `GroupBy` objects?

Comment: I don't think `__getitem__` is listed anywhere in most libraries. just like `__eq__` or `__le__`, these are Python default for corresponding ops and are not commonly listed in the docs. Instead, they're doc'ed by the ops.

Comment: @QuangHoang What do you mean by "doc'ed by the ops"? Where, in particular, is the pandas GroupBy square brackets operator documented? For instance, where is it document the type of object this operator returns?

Comment: I'm not saying that Pandas doc lists the ops. I'm just saying you shouldn't be expecting the `__getitem__` is listed in the API.

Comment: @QuangHoang The `pandas` `GroupBy` API reference documents the `__iter__` methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes I use code like below to see the source if available:

```
import inspect
import pandas

groupby_obj = pandas.DataFrame().groupby(level=0)
print(f'{type(groupby_obj)=}\n{"-"*80}')

assert '__getitem__' in dir(groupby_obj)
code = inspect.getsource(groupby_obj.__getitem__)

print(code)
```

Or rather, I just [type `??` after the functions](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html#magic-pinfo2) to see the code in Jupyter Notebook. Anyway, you can definitely see `__getitem__` in GroupBy object and read [its source code](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/fc308235f0ca6242a209c1fe19f71884fb5d50cd/pandas/core/groupby/generic.py#L1949C1-L1961C40).

As of mentioning `__getitem__` in the pandas' API reference for GroupBy, I suppose that [this part about selection in GroupBy](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/groupby.html#dataframe-column-selection-in-groupby) was intended to explain how selection works in this case.